# Player score adding to much when I press my jump key

Tags: python, pygame

So I tried to make it so that every single time I jump, my player score will add by one but so far its adding by to much, every time I jump or hold the SPACE key the score will be adding to much. I tried to write this code differently but that did not work for me.
https://gyazo.com/7854a425ac4f66783980492dae774f84

My code to add 1 to score every time player jumps[not working]

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        score += 1
        text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
        textRect.center = ((150,40))
```

My full code

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption(("Noobs First Game"))

# Player class
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 6
        self.fall = 0
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

# Platform class
class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# displaying Color
white = (255,255,255)

# Drawing player
playerman = Player(255,255,40,40,white)

# Drawing Platform
platform1 = Platform(200,300,700,30,white)

# Putting Platform in a list
platforms = [platform1]


# redrawing window
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    
    # bliting a counter the game
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    # showing player on the screen
    playerman.draw()

    # Drawing Platform
    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()

# The conter and how its going look like
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
score = 0
text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = ((150,40))


fps = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 10
y = 10

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

old_x = x
old_y = y

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()



            


        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = -7
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 7

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 0

            x += x_change
            if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
                x = old_x

            
        

    # If keys get pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px,py = playerman.x,playerman.y

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        score += 1
        text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
        textRect.center = ((150,40))
        


    # Player movment
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and playerman.x > playerman.speed:
        px -= playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and playerman.x < 700 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        px += playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and playerman.y > playerman.speed:
        py -= playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and playerman.y < 500 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        py += playerman.speed


    platform_rect_list =[p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    playerman.rect.topleft = (px,py)


    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px
        
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

            # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
                           
                # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

            # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

        
            
    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
quit_game
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score increases because the space key is held down. For the score to work correctly, you need to wait for the space key to be released.

Try this update:

```
spcdown = False
while run:
    ......

    # If keys get pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px,py = playerman.x,playerman.y
    
    if not keys[pygame.K_SPACE]: spcdown = False  # space released
    
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if not spcdown: score += 1  # if space pressed first time
        spcdown = True  # space key is pressed
        text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
        textRect.center = ((150,40))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyboard events (`KEYDOWN`, `​​KEYUP`) for actions like jumping or spawning a bullet.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

You want to increment the score just once when <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed. Therefore you should use the keyboard event `KEYDOWN`:

```py
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()


        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = -7
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 7

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                score += 1
                text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
                textRect.center = ((150,40))               
 
        
        # [...]
```